# Get sum of fields

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime-generation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL Count data for last 7 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954200/mysql-count-data-for-last-7-days)

I have an issue where i need to show the sum of fields. Lets say I have a recordset as follows,

```
detectDate      |isp    |infection  | count
--------------------------------------
2012-10-02 01:00|aaaa   |malware    |3
2012-10-02 01:30|bbbb   |malware    |2
2012-10-02 01:33|bbbb   |spy-eye    |2
2012-10-02 01:45|aaaa   |DDos       |1
2012-10-03 01:50|cccc   |malware    |2
2012-10-03 02:00|dddd   |TDSS       |2
2012-10-03 04:50|dddd   |TDSS       |3
```

And i want to display an output which will show the sum of all the infections for each day as follows,

```
detectDate  |infection  | count
-------------------------------
2012-10-02  |DDos       |1
2012-10-02  |malware    |5
2012-10-02  |spy-eye    |2
2012-10-02  |TDSS       |0
2012-10-03  |DDos       |0
2012-10-03  |malware    |2
2012-10-03  |spy-eye    |0
2012-10-03  |TDSS       |5
```

I used this query,

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( detectDate, '%Y-%m-%d' ) AS detectDate, infection, SUM( count )
FROM `tbl_correlateddata`
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT( detectDate, '%Y-%m-%d' ) , infection
```

but it only gives an out put as follows which is **NOT** my requirement..

```
detectDate  |infection  | count
-------------------------------
2012-10-02  |DDos       |1
2012-10-02  |malware    |5
2012-10-02  |spy-eye    |2
2012-10-03  |malware    |2
2012-10-03  |TDSS       |5
```

any help would be much helpful :)
Thank you very much :) much appreciated :)

**EDIT:**
Possible duplicate of : [MySQL Count data for last 7 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954200/mysql-count-data-for-last-7-days)

**but not similar**

Comment: Do you happen to have a table with all possible infections?

Comment: well one infection can occur on one date and the same infection may not appear on the next day..thats why it is 0 n thank you for the reply

Comment: ohh yeaa..thank you for pointing me to that post..its somewhat the same :)

Comment: Except that it's more complicated than you need because you don't need missing *dates* filled in, only missing *infections*, do you?

Comment: "select .......SUM( confidence )" . From where you got that confidence column????

Comment: yeaa i need missing dates and infection filled in as shown in the result i expect :)

Comment: This is related to your [Last question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13151589/1369235). Note that you have used the fields in your query which are not available in your table. (like confidence, timeStamp etc)

Comment: sorry for the confusion..i edited the question @FathahRehmanP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT e.*, COALESCE(SUM(d.`count`),0) `SUM of count`
FROM
(
  SELECT c.detectDate, a.infection
  FROM
    (
      SELECT  DISTINCT infection
      FROM    tbl_correlateddata
    ) a CROSS JOIN
    (
      SELECT  DISTINCT DATE(detectDate) detectDate 
      FROM    tbl_correlateddata 
    ) c
) e LEFT JOIN tbl_correlateddata d
    ON  DATE(d.detectDate) = e.detectDate AND
        d.infection = e.infection
 GROUP BY detectDate, infection
 ORDER BY e.detectDate, e.infection
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a229b/20)

or

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(e.detectDate, '%Y-%m-%d' ), 
        e.infection, 
        COALESCE(SUM(d.`count`),0) `SUM of count`
FROM
(
  SELECT c.detectDate, a.infection
  FROM
    (
      SELECT  DISTINCT infection
      FROM    tbl_correlateddata
    ) a CROSS JOIN
    (
      SELECT  DISTINCT DATE(detectDate) detectDate 
      FROM    tbl_correlateddata 
    ) c
) e LEFT JOIN tbl_correlateddata d
    ON  DATE(d.detectDate) = e.detectDate AND
        d.infection = e.infection
 GROUP BY e.detectDate, e.infection
 ORDER BY e.detectDate, e.infection
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a229b/25)

Comment: as always.. thank you for the answer :) but small edit, i need the `SUM of count` field.. :) and its working, :) may i know how to get 0 for those that give `null` when you use null or do i have to do it via my backend application??

Comment: @Hasitha updated. added `COALESCE`.

Comment: @JohnWoo - i. e, The life saver  +1 .